# Get the available list of SSID in iphone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to get the available list of SSID in iphone sdk through code?  If so, could you get me sample code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple80211GetInfoCopy](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211GetInfoCopy) is the function you're looking for.

Comment: Careful.  Use of this private library will prevent you from being able to submit it to the app store.  They'll deny it immediately.